# Emacs - selecting a match from helm-multi-swoop-all produces the error "Symbol's value as variable is void: $buf"

Tags: emacs, elisp, emacs-helm

I can run `helm-multi-swoop-all` in emacs and see all the matches, but when I press enter to select one the error `"Symbol's value as variable is void: $buf"` appears in the minibuffer and helm doesn't actually open the buffer/line with the match.

Any idea why this is/how to fix it?

Comment: Pull request which fixes this issue is already sent https://github.com/ShingoFukuyama/helm-swoop/pull/80 . However this is not merged.